# Calculate corresponding time interval based on other condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataset `df` as below:

```
Time    Temperature
17:29:33    18
8:23:04     18.5
8:23:04     19
9:12:57     19
9:12:57     20
9:12:58     20
9:12:58     21
9:12:59     21
9:12:59     23
9:13:00     23
9:13:00     25
9:13:01     25
9:13:01     27
9:13:02     27
9:13:02     28
9:13:03     28
```

which constantly records temperature data whenever there is a temperature change that is greater than 0.5°C.

I want to calculate the total time duration where the temperature is between 25°C-40°C **(ie. if the spikes exceed 40°C, the corresponding time will not be taken into account)**. How can I do this in Python?

Edited:
Below is a plot for better illustration of the dataset. 
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output for the dataset in your question?

Comment: For example , will you have the situation like 25,20,25,26,28,29,20,25,26,27 ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I would like to conduct data visualisation on this dataset, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S, usually not. Please see the edited question for a plot for better illustration of the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the temperature can be between 25 and 40 and out of range we probably need to calculate the duration of different intervals, so I use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) here

```
l=25
h = 40
measure_range = df['Temperature'].between(l,h)
df_range = df.loc[measure_range]
groups = (~measure_range).cumsum()
intervals_df = (pd.to_datetime(df_range['Time'].astype(str))
                  .groupby(groups)
                  .agg(['first','last'])
                  .reset_index(drop=True)
                  .assign(Total_time=lambda x: x.diff(axis =1).iloc[:,-1],
                          first = lambda x: x['first'].dt.time,
                          last = lambda x: x['last'].dt.time)
                  )
print(intervals_df)
      first      last Total_time
0  09:13:00  09:13:03   00:00:03
```

in this way a row is generated in the dataframe for each time interval in which the temperature is between `l` and `h` continuously.

Answer (score 2):

Do it step by step , `numpy.ptp` is a way to calculate the max and min different from `numpy`

```
df.Time=pd.Timedelta(df.Time)

s = df.Temperature.between(25,40)
out = df[s].groupby((~s).cumsum()).Time.agg(['min', 'max', np.ptp])
                 min      max      ptp
Temperature                           
10          09:13:00 09:13:03 00:00:03
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. It returned `ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible`. Do you know why is that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the time column is in the right format.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'],unit='s')
```

Get the time when temp reaches 40. (Tail gives you the most recent temp. You can use head() if required). Reset index to get the diff later.

```
temp_40 = df[df['temp'] == 40]['time'].tail(1)
temp_40 = temp_40.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Similarly, get the time when the temp reached 25.

```
temp_25 = df[df['temp'] == 25]['time'].tail(1)
temp_25 = temp_25.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Now get the diff

```
temp_40 - temp_25
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It returned `0   -1 days +22:57:24     Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]` but what does this mean? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `-1 days` indicate that the time for `40` is less than that of `25` . You need to have `time` column in `24h` format.

Comment: Do you know how I can convert to 24h format? Thanks!